# Swashes: What are they?

Tags: names, products

I always thought `swashes` were a way to call wet wipes/wet tissues/wet towels/moist towelettes -or- whatever you call them.

Recently, though, I realized that Swashes is actually a company that makes this stuff. Do other people use `swashes` as a word for wet wipes? or am I just being crazy?

Comment: Personally, I've never heard of that (or the brand, for that matter—I'd just call them wet wipes and not have a clue who made them). Swashes to me are ornamental extra strokes found in variant glyphs in fonts, nothing else that I can think of.

Comment: Of the first 50 Google hits on "swashes" where I am, in the middle of the US, 38 involve Janus Bahs Jacquet's meaning, 3 involve a software product, 2 involve the verb *swash*, 4 involve *swashbuckling*, and only three involve the product name: two links to the company's website (one in English, one in Chinese characters) and this very question. The use is probably only current in the company's market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just one of those cases where the brand is so strong to become the name of the product itself. No need to worry about it.

- a glass of scotch is a glass of whiskey

Comment: Of course, scotch is not a brand name in the case of whiskey. The brand name Scotch I would associate with Scotch tape, which I see and hear used a lot for _any_ brand of adhesive tape :)

Answer (score 2):

"Swash" is a word that means any number of things:

> [swash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/swash)
>
> — verb (used without object)
>
> 1. to splash, as things in water, or as water does: Waves were swashing against the piers.
> 2. to dash around, as things in violent motion.
> 3. to swagger.
>
> — verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to dash or cast violently, especially to dash (water or other liquid) around, down, etc.
>
> — noun
>
> 1. the surging or dashing, sometimes violent, of water, waves, etc.
> 2. the sound made by such dashing: the thunderous swash of the waves.
> 3. the ground over which water washes.
> 4. Chiefly Southeastern U.S.  a channel of water through or behind a sandbank.
> 5. Printing.  an extending ornamental flourish, as on letters of certain fonts of italic or cursive type.

As for the brand "Swashes", it is not intended to be associated with the specific product you mentioned:

> Swash is a brand of laundry products manufactured by Procter & Gamble (P&G). [It] is made up of previously-existing P&G products[, including] a spray to remove odors, a stain-erasing pen, a spray to remove wrinkles, and a cloth which removes wrinkles and odors when placed in a dryer with clothes.

To directly answer your question:

> Recently, though, I realized that Swashes is actually a company that makes this stuff. Do other people use swashes as a word for wet wipes? or am I just being crazy?

Your usage is abnormal and most likely isolated to your immediate region.